# Opening submenu links in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
  $('#linksobsah').children().hide().eq(0).show();     

  $('#links').children().click(function() {
  $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
  var index = $('#links').children().index(this);
  $('#linksobsah').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);               
  $('#links').children().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
  });
});
```

The JSFiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/m92rga7h/

When i click to Link 1 everything works well. The submenu show and when i click on some submenu it shows current content. But it does not work for Link 2 but the code is still the same in html and a jQuery too.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you were trying to show first ul in linksobsah on click of link2. actually for link 2 you should query second ul in linksobsah.

use this `$('#linksobsah ul:eq( 1 )'`) // index 1 means second ul

instead of  `$('#linksobsah ul')` in link 2.

working js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/taod03by/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
     $('#linksobsah').children().hide().eq(0).show();     
 
   $('#links').children().click(function() {
      $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
      var index = $('#links').children().index(this);
      $('#linksobsah').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);               
   $('#links').children().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#menulink1').children().hide();     
   $('#linksobsah ul').children().click(function() {
      $('#linksobsah ul').find('li').addClass('active');
   var index = $('#linksobsah ul').children().index(this);
      $('#menulink1').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);               
   $('#linksobsah ul').children().removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
     });

 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menulink2').children().hide();     
   $('#linksobsah ul:eq( 1 )').children().click(function() {
     $('#linksobsah ul:eq( 1 )').find('li').addClass('active');
   var index = $('#linksobsah ul:eq( 1 )').children().index(this);
     $('#menulink2').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);               
   $('#linksobsah ul:eq( 1 )').children().removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active'); 
    });
     });



// JavaScript Document
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
<div class="link1">
<div class="linktext">Link1</div>
</div>
<div class="link2">
<div class="linktext">Link2</div>
</div>
<div class="link3">
<div class="linktext">Link3</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="linksobsah">
<div>
<ul>
<li>Link 1 submenu 1</li>
<li>Link 1 submenu 2</li>
<li>Link 1 submenu 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="menulink1">
<div>Link 1 submenu 1 content</div>
<div>Link 1 submenu 2 content</div>
<div>Link 1 submenu 3 content</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Link 2 submenu 1</li>
<li>Link 2 submenu 2</li>
<li>Link 2 submenu 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="menulink2">
<div>Link 2 submenu 1 content</div>
<div>Link 2 submenu 2 content</div>
<div>Link 2 submenu 3 content</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `class="menulink"` instead of `id` because id is unique for whole document

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
  $('#linksobsah').children().hide().eq(0).show();

  $('#links').children().click(function() {
    $('#links').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    var index = $('#links').children().index(this);
    $('#linksobsah').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);
    $('#links').children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menulink').children().hide();
  $('#linksobsah ul').children().click(function() {
    $('#linksobsah ul').find('li').addClass('active');
    var index = $('#linksobsah ul').children().index(this);
    $('#menulink1').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500);
    $('#linksobsah ul').children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menulink2').children().hide();
  $('#linksobsah ul').children().click(function() {
    $('#linksobsah ul').find('li').addClass('active');
    var index = $('#linksobsah ul').children().index(this);
    $('.menulink').children().hide(100).eq(index).show(500); //change with class instead of id
    $('#linksobsah ul').children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});



// JavaScript Document
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links">
  <div class="link1">
    <div class="linktext">Link1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link2">
    <div class="linktext">Link2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="link3">
    <div class="linktext">Link3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="linksobsah">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 1 submenu 1</li>
      <li>Link 1 submenu 2</li>
      <li>Link 1 submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="menulink1" class="menulink"><!--class name-->
      <div>Link 1 submenu 1 content</div>
      <div>Link 1 submenu 2 content</div>
      <div>Link 1 submenu 3 content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>Link 2 submenu 1</li>
      <li>Link 2 submenu 2</li>
      <li>Link 2 submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="menulink2" class="menulink">
      <div>Link 2 submenu 1 content</div>
      <div>Link 2 submenu 2 content</div>
      <div>Link 2 submenu 3 content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```